# $x=\frac{1}{2}a(1-\cos(\alpha))$ substition in Bernoullie's brachistochrone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

When Bernoulli in brachistochrone calculus got to step
$$y=a \sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)-\sqrt{ax-x^2}$$
he substituted $$x=\dfrac{1}{2}a(1-\cos(\alpha))$$
and got
$$y=\frac{1}{2}a\alpha-\frac{1}{2}a \sin(\alpha)$$
Where did this substitution come from?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get rid of the $sin^{-1}(\sqrt {...} )$ one may need $sin^2$ for their parameter changing.

We can say:

$\sin^2(\alpha/2)=\dfrac{1+cos(2\alpha)}{2}=x/a \to x=a\sin^2(\alpha/2)=a \cdot \dfrac{1+cos(2\alpha)}{2}$
$\to x=\dfrac{1}{2}a(1-cos(\alpha))$

In other words:

$x=\dfrac{1}{2}a(1-cos(\alpha))=a\sin^2(\alpha/2) \to y=a \cdot \alpha/2 -asin(\alpha)/2$

Comment: And why does $sin^2(α/2)=x/a$ ? i don't see it

Comment: $x=\dfrac{1}{2}a(1-cos(\alpha))=a\sin^2(\alpha/2)$ because of the general formula: $sin^2(\theta)=\dfrac{1-cos(2\theta)}{2}$. As a result: $sin^2(α/2)=x/a$ @Ralnor